# When and why did English change Affrick and Asie to Africa and Asia?

Tags: etymology, toponyms, geography

English names for continents all end in Latin suffix ***-a / -ia***, except *Europe*.

*Africa, America, Antarctica, Asia, Australia*

Since English language used to take much of its vocabulary from French during Middle Ages (incl. some suffixes, e.g. *-y* (← Fr. *-ie*) as in *Italy*), I was wondering why English names for continents are not formed after French instead, containing the French suffix ***-e***.

*Afrique, Amerique, Antarctique, Asie, Australie*

As I found out, Africa and Asia, the two Old World continents, actually DID have the French suffix. According to Wiktionary:

- *Africa* comes from Middle English *Affrike*, from Old French *Affrique*, *Affrike*. Obsolete names for *Africa* include *Affrike*, *Afric*, *Africk*.
- *Asia* comes from Middle English *Asia, Asie*, from Old French *Asie* and Latin *Asia*.

And *Europe* still retains its French *-e*.

Obviously, the English language changed the French suffixes (*-e*) for Latin ones (*-a*). And obviously, this change was not natural but rather artificial/external. (And the neologisms *America, Australia* and *Antarctica* were then created in this fashion.)

When and why did this change happen?

When people were used to *Affrick* and *Asie*, how did they accept new names, *Africa* and *Asia*?

Why did not *Europe* change to *Europa*?

Comment: In Middle English, final -e was not usually silent, so the idea that Africa has more syllables than Affrike is questionable. It's also a gross simplification to say "English language used to take its vocabulary from French during Middle Ages" as though French was a single unchanging language and English had no other sources.

Comment: It's also a mistake to think the goal of language is to make words as short as possible. Having a characteristic ending like -a or -ia can be useful.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you for pointing out my mistakes, I fixed them.

Answer (score 3):

In Middle English, both -e and -a were used for all three words. (Not surprising as spelling was widely variable, especially when it came to vowels.) Here's Aelfric (1175) using the -a forms:

> Þe ðry delas beoð idælede ðurh heom [Noah], Asia on eastrice ðam ealdestan sunu, Affrica on suðdælæ ðes Chames cynnes, & Europa on norðdæle, Iapheðes ofsprunges.

And here's *Confessio Amantis* (a1393; c1300) with -e forms:

> Asie, Aufrique, Europe..Als ferr as streccheth eny ground, Begripeth al this Erthe round.

If the quotes I found (searching the Middle English Dictionary) are representative, then both -e forms of *Asia* and *Africa* were used around 1200 and *Europe* appeared a little after that (1300).